# Is there a Doc2vec model in tensorflow?

Tags: nlp, tensorflow

I know I am not suppose to ask for a tool, resource, etc on stackoverflow: But I think this is an important question and people will benefit from it. Here comes the question: I have found word2vec but failed to find doc2vec implementation in the tensorflow package, and will be surprised if it is not supported in tensorflow.

Comment: haven't tested it, but this might help https://github.com/sachinruk/doc2vec_tf

Answer (score 2):

I guess that will be very slow,  TensorFlow does not support so-called “inline” matrix operations, but forces you to copy a matrix in order to perform an operation on it. Copying very large matrices is costly in every sense. TF takes 4x as long as the state of the art deep learning tools. Google says it’s working on the problem. [Source](http://deeplearning4j.org/compare-dl4j-torch7-pylearn.html)

you can go ahead and implement it on your own which is not hard as there are many types of word2vec implementations but the question remains, is it useful and fast?